# mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied in DB insert

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I am trying to use a legacy MediaWiki extension on PHP 5.6 and later versions, and it fails when it comes to DB inserts.

**And yes, this is not a duplicate, as the code is different.**

The full error was:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I tried changing to `mysqli_real_escape_string` but then I had:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on
>   line 235

Here is the function:

```
function Lookup_addLookup ($url, $name, $group)
{
    $dbw = wfGetDB(DB_MASTER);

    $groupOrder = Lookup_getGroupOrder($group);
    $dbw->query ("INSERT INTO ".Lookup_prefix()."lookups (lu_name, lu_url, lu_group, lu_order, lu_group_order) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($url)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($group)."', 1, $groupOrder)");

    Lookup_reOrderGroups();
    return true;
}
```

And another one further down:

```
function Lookup_moveGroupUp($group)
{
    $dbw = wfGetDB(DB_MASTER);

    $dbw->query ("UPDATE ".Lookup_prefix()."lookups SET lu_group_order = 0 WHERE lu_group = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($group)."'");

    Lookup_reOrderGroups();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_real\_escape\_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in... Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776004/warning-mysqli-real-escape-string-expects-exactly-2-parameters-1-given-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` needs the database link as the first parameter, which is why it isn't working.

However, MediaWiki [wants us to avoid direct queries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/SQL_injection#SQL_Injection_and_MediaWiki), so it has the [`$dbw->insert()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikimedia_1_1Rdbms_1_1Database.html#a14d41a27ab0c194a68b9fc45199a92b9) method instead, one of several [wrapper functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_access#Wrapper_functions).

Use something like this:

```php
function Lookup_addLookup ($url, $name, $group)
{
    $dbw = wfGetDB(DB_MASTER);

    $groupOrder = Lookup_getGroupOrder($group);
    $dbw->insert(
        Lookup_prefix()."lookups",
        array(
            'lu_name'  => $name,
            'lu_url'   => $url,
            'lu_group' => $group,
            'lu_order' => 1,
            'lu_group_order' => $groupOrder
        )
    );

    Lookup_reOrderGroups();
    return true;
}
```

And in the second example, use [`$dbw->update()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikimedia_1_1Rdbms_1_1Database.html#a9fc9daada8a7a131dc4baea127c2063a):

```php
function Lookup_moveGroupUp($group)
{
    $dbw = wfGetDB(DB_MASTER);

    $dbw->update(
        Lookup_prefix()."lookups",
        array(
            "lu_group_order" => 0
        ),
        array(
            "lu_group" => $group
        )
    );

    Lookup_reOrderGroups();

    return true;
}
```

For more information and other SQL wrappers, read about the [different wrapper functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_access#Wrapper_functions) and their [documentation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikimedia_1_1Rdbms_1_1Database.html).

Comment: Thank you! That gave me:  
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given on line 235 [It is the line starting with $dbw->query]

Comment: @greektranslator How about this?

Comment: Damn, I have another one further down (I edited original post)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the extra query help, I tried but could not figure it out.